# Discrete Math Clause Count Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Ok, I'm completely lost if anyone could hint me through some of the first steps that would be hugely appreciative!!

In a CNF formula, a clause contains one or more terms. Each term is either 
a variable, or the negation of a variable. The only limitations we will place 
on the clauses (for this problem) is that if a clause mentions a variable (or its 
negation) once, then it must not mention the same variable (or its negation) 
again. Therefore, both of the following clauses are disallowed: 
(a ∨ b ∨ a) 
(a ∨ b ∨ ¬a) 
However, your program might well generate similar clauses with different 
negation patterns. The following are four different clauses: 
(a ∨ b),(a ∨ ¬b),(¬a ∨ b),(¬a ∨ ¬b)

Part (a) - 
In general, as your program runs, it will generate larger and larger clauses, 
with a maximum of v terms per clause, if there were v variables mentioned in 
the original formula. 
Calculate the number of possible clauses which have exactly n terms, if the 
original formula mentioned v variables

Part (b) - 
Calculate the sum total number of clauses (of various sizes) 
that your program might generate, if the original formula mentioned v 
variables.

Part (c) - 
Suppose the original formula mentioned 
v variables, but every single clause had two or fewer terms. Calculate the total number of clauses which your program might generate.

Part (d) 
Based on your result from Part (b), give a very rough (thousands, millions, etc) estimate of how many clauses your program might generate if v=10, and the clauses in the original formula can be of any size. 
What would happen if v were to double? How does the count change?

Comment: __Hint__: there are three possibilities for a given variable (literal) in a clause. It can be absent, positive or negated. How many different numbers can you build with $v$ digits and three different values per digit? Keep in mind that there must be at least one variable present in each clause.

Comment: so it is a combo problem kind of.  If there has to be at least 1 variable in each clause how can we guarantee that? Because wouldn't 3^v be the total combos possible, which there is a chance to get no variables present? Also where does n come from? how would we determine how many have n terms?

Comment: What will happen if we double the size of V ?

Comment: How do you even get to the the formula for all everything in order to double V

Answer (score 0):

a) You have v variables. How many clauses can you form that have n variables?
   There are $v \choose n$ ways to choose the n variables. For each of the n variables, 
   you have a choice of the variable or its negation. There are $2^n$ choices. So, in    total $S_n$ = $v \choose n$ $2^n$

b) This is simply the sum of $S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_v$

c) This is simply $S_1 + S_2$

d) Compare the answer in part (b) for v = 10 and v = 20

Comment: For part b, I believe you aren't restricted by the $n$ variable limit.  So, would it just be something like $v!2^v$ or something along those lines?

Comment: My mistake. Part (b) should be the sum of $S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_v$